# How to solve linear equation in android?

Tags: java, math, equation

i want to know how to solve equations in android

my equation is as under:-
`SV = A*((1-R)^N) * (1-(R*(M/12)))`

where SV is some value,
A is Amount,
R is Rate,
N is years,
M is Months.

i want to find **R**

i don't know how to do this in **coding**
let me know if any additional **lib** files are also required.

Comment: Please rephrase the question by giving domains for the values, include a reference to Java and provide a bit more context. I hope the question will be reopened and answered with the comments below.

Answer (score 1):

I tried simplifying the above and I reached this point,

```
SV = A * ((1-R)^N) * (1-(R*(M/12)))
SV = A * (1-R)^N * (1-R) * (1-(M/12))

(1-R)^ N+1 = SV/ (A * (1-(M/12))

(1-R) = (N+1) root of (SV/ (A * (1-(M/12)))

R = ((N+1) root of (SV/ (A * (1-(M/12)))) + 1
```

Now, all the Values on the RHS are known and can be replaced. Hope this helps. I am also keen for the output.

Comment: Very good - the `n+1`-th root could then be calculated via
`Math.pow( Value, ( 1.0f / ( N+1.0f ) ) )` and there would be no need for the binary search.

Comment: The second step seems to be incorrect, `1-R(M/12)` is not equak to `(1-R)*(1-(M/12))`.

Comment: I agree - I don't think the algebra is correct.

Comment: this gives wrong results, your algebra is not correct..

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange the formula by dividing by `A`, then consider right-hand side without `A`. Perhaps `R` is to be constrained to lie between 1 and 0? The resulting right-hand side seems to be monotonically decreasing in `R` on the interval (0,1), so the desired value of `R` can be approximated by binary search. It can be done with the following code in Java.

```
double R( double SV, double A, double N, double M){
  double DESIRED_ACCURACY = 0.01f; // customize this value
  double targetvalue = SV / A;     // left hand side after rearranging
  double upperbound = 1.0f;        // bounds for binary search
  double lowebound = 0.0f;

  double frac = M / 12.0f;

  while ( upperbound - lowebound > accuracy ){
      double mid = ( upperbound - lowerbound ) / 2.0f;
      double evaluation = Math.Pow( 1.0f - midpoint, N ) * ( 1.0f - midpoint * frac );
      if ( evaluation > targetvalue ){
        upperbound = midpoint;
      } else {
         lowerbound = midpoint;
      }
  }

  return ( upperbound - lowerboud ) / 2.0f;
}
```

Comment: i have updated my question with my equation, have a look...

Comment: It is a bit more difficult as `N` is used as an exponent. Is something more known about `N` - ideally the specific value?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Perhaps it can be done with an approach that is mathematically simpler?

Comment: N is years, it is input provided by user

Comment: i just want to know the valur of 'R' i.e Rate

Comment: I have updated my answer; does `R` indeed lie between 0 and 1?

Comment: yes,'R' is between 0 to 1.